# Linux how to check if parent process exists?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In linux we can access process parent like this:

```
current->parent
```

my question is how can we check if the parent still exists?

The reason is that I am implementing a loop that visits all ancestors of current process and want to know when to stop.

Comment: *"want to know when to stop"* - what does it mean? Please clarify

Comment: Are you writting a kernel module or a user program?

Answer (score 1):

When the parent of a particular process exits, the child is inherited by the init process.

So you can check if the parent process is running if `getppid()` returns a value other than 1.

Comment: @daniel So? What is the problem to check if parent is `1`?